# Exporting Data From Microsoft Service Trace Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, profiling

I am doing some profiling on a WCF service and I want to compare the trace times for two different processes running the same methods at different speeds. Is there a way to export the data from Microsoft Service Trace Viewer to excel or something like that to be able to compare the resulting profile? I am using [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx) as a reference to set up the trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I needed to compare two WCF traces to see why one didn't work and one did.  I did not find any comparison tools for an svclog and the XML output I had for the trace was all on one line in the file, making it very difficult to compare in a standard comparison tool.

With this in mind, I renamed the *.svclog file to *.config.  I then opened the file in Visual Studio and used CTRL+K, CTRL+D to format the document.  This added standard XML formatting (with line breaks) to the log file.  With the output in separate lines, I could use a standard file comparison tool.  I used WinMerge for comparison.

Visual Studio Shortcuts:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#bkmk_edit

WinMerge:  http://winmerge.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was working with a very large json object at the time... Would this be effective with that?

Comment: I don't see why not.  It certainly would be more data to sift through, but WinMerge should be able to show you any differences effectively.